# How i can take the integer in string from a row in csv file to python?

Tags: python, excel, csv

Hy guys my teacher has assing me to get the integer from a row string in one column. This all thing is going to be by read a csv file with the help from python.So my terminal dosen't hit but i dont get nothing as a guide problem, i want from every row to take the integer and print them.

**Here is my code :**

```
import pandas as pd

tx = [ "T4.csv" ]


for name_csv in tx : 
  df = pd.read_csv( name_csv, names=["A"])
  for row in df: 
   if row == ('NSIT ,A: ,'):
     # i dont know how to use the split for to take the integer and print them !!!!
        print("A",row)
   else 
     # i dont know how to use the split for to take the integer and print them !!!!
     print("B",row)
```

**Also here is and what it have the the csv file :(i have the just them all in the column A)**

```
 NSIT ,A: ,-213

 NSIT ,A: ,-43652

 NSIT ,B: ,-39

 NSIT ,A: ,-2

 NSIT ,B: ,-46
```

*At the end i have put my try on python, i hope you guys to understand the problem i have.*

Comment: Not sure why you're using *pandas* for this - it's really not necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the file one line at a time. Split each line on comma. Print the last item in the resulting list.

```
with open('T4.csv') as data:
    for line in data:
        len(tokens := line.split(',')) == 3:
            print(tokens[2])
```

**Alternative:**

```
with open('T4.csv') as data:
    d = {}
    for line in data:
        if len(tokens := line.split(',')) == 3:
            _, b, c = map(str.strip, tokens)
            d.setdefault(b, []).append(c)
    for k, v in d.items():
        print(k, end='')
        print(*v, sep=',', end='')
        print(f' sum={sum(map(int, v))}')
```

**Output:**

```
A:-213,-43652,-2 sum=-43867
B:-39,-46 sum=-85
```

Comment: @fjordi Not sure what "sepers" means. Edit your question to show what the output should look like

Comment: sorry but i forgot to mantion , but if you can to print the A **separate from B numbers, so in the forwart i can to sum the  A  and  B numbers ?

Comment: @fjordi I have no idea what that means

Comment: sorry again , i want to count how many are the A node nubers, like i want to print the sum and the how many are ( for example the A is 3 numbers ,aslo the B ar 2 numbers),for i print  A , 3=count , sum= -43867

Comment: @Lilfio Just print the length of each value (which is a list) in the dictionary

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.read_csv( "T4.csv", names=["c1", "c2", "c3"])
print(df.c3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question was not very clear. So I assume you want to print out the 3rd column of the CSV file. I also think that you opened the CSV file in Excel, which is why you see that all the data is put in Column A.

A CSV (comma-separated values) file is a plain text file that contains data organised as a table of rows and columns, where each row represents a record, and each column represents a field or attribute of the form.

A newline character typically separates each row of data in a CSV file, and the values in each column are separated by a delimiter character, such as a comma (,). For example, here is a simple CSV file with three rows and three columns:

```
S.No, Student Name, Student Roll No.

1, Alpha, 123

2, Beta, 456

3, Gamma, 789
```

For a simple application like what you mention, Pandas might not be required. You can use the standard `csvreader` library of Python to do this.
Please find the code below to print out the 3rd column of your CSV file.

```
import csv

with open("T4.csv") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=",")
    headers = next(csv_reader)  # Get the column headers
    print(headers[2])  # Print the 3rd column header
    for row in csv_reader:
        print(row[2])  # Print the 3rd column data
```